# Would it be possible to edit a mac app and add website address as a Help menu link?

Tags: macos, nib

I'm interested in teaching myself how to build and edit mac apps, but I'm really new to it, and it's more for fun right now. I found some open source apps on github to play around with, and I noticed that in one of them, there is no web address link for their website on the Help menu (example, it shows `App Name | File | Edit | View | Window | Help`).

Would it be possible to edit that app somehow and add the address as a Help menu link? If so, where would I go or how would I achieve this? I looked in the App/Contents/Resources and there are some .nib files, but I'm not sure if the menu information is stored in a .nib or if it's in a .plist file or somewhere else? Would I need to have XCode installed in order to edit and add this?

I am quite new to this, but I'm wanting to do this for self exploration and learning.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be possible to edit that app somehow and add the address as a Help menu link?

It's generally not possible to edit an existing app and accomplish what you are looking for.

> I found some open source apps on github to play around with, and I noticed that in one of them, there is no web address link for their website on the Help menu.

For an open source app, you can ask the developers to incorporate the change by either opening an [issue](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/creating-an-issue) or contributing the change in the source code yourself.